# Are there humans in the world of Redwall?

Tags: redwall

Throughout the three *Redwall* books that i have read, (*Redwall, Mattimeo,* and *Mossflower*) there are only animals, such as mice, moles, foxes, etc.

**Is there any mention of humans in any of the books?**

Comment: ive read all but his last 2 books, and there are no humans, as yohann says there is a horse, and it would seem in redwall itself the thought of humans being around existed in the authors mind because the rats are riding a human sized wagon attached to a horse, but the rest of the books no longer even have horses in them, and everything is scaled down to accurate sizes for the animals.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No there aren't.

According the [FAQ](http://www.redwall.org/faq.php) on Brian Jacques' official Redwall website;

> **Q:** *I have just started your books. I have read Redwall and am now working
>   on Mattimeo. At the beginning of Redwall there is the "riderless
>   horsecart" and now in Mattimeo there is mention of a ship that sank.
>   Are there humans somewhere in the realm of Redwall?*
>
> **BJ:** ***No, there are no humans,*** my first book Redwall did mention the horse
>   and cart but no humans are ever in the stories and I don't intend that
>   they should ever be. The ships are generally crewed by vermin.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that Redwall was the first book published in 1986. Cluny arrives in a large hay cart pulled by a horse. In dialogue later on the elders recall from old records accounts of Cluny's hoard stampeding cattle through villages. Only conjecture on my part, but I think the series evolved quickly to exclude humans all together.

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of a tricky question. It seems as though Brian Jacques intended humans to be in the Redwall world in the first book (the horse and cart etc.), but quickly changed his mind. However, there are hints that a human world lies somewhere far far beyond the sea. Some pieces of evidence were when the creatures of Salamandastron found what they called a "coin" on the beach (Sable Queen book) and when the wildcat leader in High Rulain says that the other cats are feral, and used to be "tame" and serve "stronger beasts" across the seas, but were liberated by his kind long ago.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If you read the quote in the first answer, the author states that humans are _not_ in the world.  Do you have evidence that the author is wrong about his own books?

Comment: You're right that humans are not in the books, and there are no clear mentions of them, but you must admit that there are some interesting pieces of evidence that suggest there might be a human world somewhere far away. I believe it suggests that humans are not in the world of redwall, but are in a different world, or perhaps used to be long ago.